# 'Error -5 while decompressing data' in Spark, in PyPDF2 lib

Tags: python, pyspark, zlib, pypdf

Does anybody know why this occurs:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1089.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1089.0 (TID 1951, ip-10-0-208-38.ec2.internal): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 101, in main
    process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 96, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 236, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-762-e1c8f006c3c2>", line 4, in getPdfData
  File "<ipython-input-762-e1c8f006c3c2>", line 85, in extractData
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 2566, in extractText
    content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 2644, in __init__
    stream = BytesIO(b_(stream.getData()))
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 837, in getData
    decoded._data = filters.decodeStreamData(self)
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/filters.py", line 346, in decodeStreamData
    data = FlateDecode.decode(data, stream.get("/DecodeParms"))
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/filters.py", line 111, in decode
    data = decompress(data)
  File "./addedFile3142227314340912289bfddea6e_2a71_413e_b077_a4493987f9d9_PyPDF2-12df7.egg/PyPDF2/filters.py", line 49, in decompress
    return zlib.decompress(data)
error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

I process PDF files on workers using PyPDF2, creating a PyPDFpdfObject, calling getDocumentInfo() and calling extract_text() on the pageObjects. Im not explicitly using the zlib module where this 'compression' error usually occurs according to the oracle called the internet.
My code runs perfectly fine for smaller number of PDF's (around 500 or so) stored in an RDD (3 workers), but when I scale it up to 5000 or higher it goes wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody any idea? I still haven't figured why it can't process the PDF's. Maybe its because there's just 2 workers that have to do too much work? But then why doesn't it give a memory error?

Comment: Have you processed all 5000 of your PDFs 500 at a time to prove to yourself you don't have a bad PDF?

Comment: Yeah so it probably was a bad PDF, but I just can't seem to figure out why. It does not give a good reason for why the PDF is bad. I just caught the exception and moved on with my life.

Comment: Please update pypdf. I think this issue might be fixed.